# Distribution of max of samples with replacement

Tags: distributions, sampling

Suppose you have a set of numbers $\{1,2,...,m\}$ where $m \ge 5$ .  Now you randomly choose five of those elements with replacement, $\text{a}_1$ ... $\text{a}_5$.

What is the distribution of max($\text{a}_1$,$\text{a}_2$,$\text{a}_3$,$\text{a}_4$,$\text{a}_5$)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let X = max(A1,A2,A3,A4,A5). That means $Pr(X <= x) = Pr(A1<=x, A2 <= x, A3 <= x, A4 <= x, A5<x) = Pr(A1<=x)Pr(A2<=x)Pr(A3<=x)Pr(A4<=x)Pr(A5<=5)$ (by independence).

That means $Pr(max(A1,A2,A3,A4,A5) <= x) = Pr(A_i <= x)^5$.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like homework. So just a hint: calculate the cumulative distribution function $$F_{X}(x) = P(X \leq x)$$
with X being the maximum of your five draws. Start with $x = m$ which is the probability of none of your five draws being $m$. When you have the cumulative distribution function it is straightforward to get the distribution.

Comment: Actually, it's not homework.  It comes from a probabilistic approach to cache eviction in an "LRU" cache.  Pick 5 items at random and evict the least recently used.  I'm just trying to get a sense for how much worse that is than choosing the least recently used item exactly.