# Distribution of MLE of $N$ based on a random sample of size n from discrete uniform dist.(1,2,...,$N$)

Tags: maximum-likelihood, discrete-data, uniform-distribution

Let $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ be a random sample from discrete uniform distribution on $(1,2,\ldots,N)$, where $N$ is an unknown positive integer. Find MLE of $N$ and also find the distribution of the MLE.

I have been able to find the MLE. Fairly obvious, it is $X_{(n)}$, the $n^{th}$ order statistic, if I am not mistaken. Can anyone help regarding the second part?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated. Is this a homework question? If so, you may want to have a look at [our meta-question about how to ask these properly](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/q/12/32036).

Answer (score 2):

You now know that $\hat{N}_{MLE} = X_{(n)}$. Now to find the distribution you want to find $Pr(X_{(n)} \leq x) = Pr(\mathrm{max}(X_1, X_2, ...X_n) \leq x)$.

The solution to that final probability I have already solved in the accepted answer here:
[Distribution of max of samples with replacement](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/93336/distribution-of-max-of-samples-with-replacement/93339#93339)