# Expected Value of Naive Recommender System

Tags: distributions, sampling, expected-value, recommender-system

Let $k, n \in \mathbb{N}$, with $k \leq n$. Let $A = (a_1, a_2, ..., a_n)$ be an unordered finite sequence of real numbers. Let $(B_1, B_2, ..., B_k)$ be an unordered sequence of random variables such that each $B_i$ is sampled uniformly from $A$, ***without*** replacement. Let the random variable $X = max(B_1, B_2, ..., B_k)$.

What is the distribution $p(X)$? What is the expected value $\mathbb{E}[X]$. (The former would go a long way to compute the latter.)

This is very similar to [Distribution of max of samples with replacement](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/93336/distribution-of-max-of-samples-with-replacement), except here the collection in question possibly has duplicate values and the sampling is without replacement.

In the context of recommendation systems, $a_i$ is the relevancy or score of some document or item $d_i$. A system may be allowed to recommend $k$ of the $n$ documents (an internet search engine may recommend 10 pages out of billions). $\mathbb{E}[X]$ is the expected relevancy or score of the naive recommendation system which chooses $k$ documents uniformly at random and without replacement.

This seems related to the [Urn Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urn_problem), the [Multivariate Hypergeometric Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution#Multivariate_hypergeometric_distribution), and [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11222-010-9174-3); but here, the balls have a number instead of a color and we are interested in value of the balls instead of counts.

(Any corrections to the concepts, terminology, or even notation/syntax are welcome.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a Python solution to compute the expected value, created by [NabiNaga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3063568/nabinaga). By sorting the values in $A$, we can compute the cumulative distribution of $X$. The probability of $X$ is then the cumulative probability of a particular value from sorted $A$ minus the cumulative probability of the value that comes before it. The probability that $X$ assumes one of the $k-1$ smallest values is $0$, unless there are duplicates. The `brute_force` method verifies that this handles duplicate values in $A$.

```
from functools import reduce
from itertools import combinations
import operator as op


def ncr(n, r):
    # from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941753/is-there-a-math-ncr-function-in-python
    r = min(r, n - r)
    numer = reduce(op.mul, range(n, n - r, -1), 1)
    denom = reduce(op.mul, range(1, r + 1), 1)
    return numer / denom


def brute_force(A, k):
    total = 0
    count = 0
    for combination in combinations(A, k):
        total += max(combination)
        count += 1
    return total / count


def solve(A, k):
    assert k <= len(A)
    A = sorted(A)

    total = 0
    last_num_combs = 0
    for i in range(k, len(A) + 1):
        num_combs = ncr(i, k)
        X = A[i - 1]
        total += X * (num_combs - last_num_combs)
        last_num_combs = num_combs

    return total / last_num_combs


if __name__ == "__main__":
    A = [1, 3, 7, 10, 15, 20, 20, 100, 100, 112, 150]
    k = 5

    assert brute_force(A, k) == solve(A, k)
    print(solve(A, k))
```